# How to Add/Edit/Delete from/to MySQL DB with jqGrid

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I'm a jQuery/jqGrid newbie...

I've got my jqGrid selecting and displaying my data correctly. I also have the edit/add buttons adding/editing data on my grid. However, I'm not sure how I make those adds/edits update MySQL database. Any suggestions?

Here is my scripts.js file:

```
 $("#table-maintenance-conflicts").jqGrid(
    { 
        url:'maintenanceConflicts.php', 
        editurl:'maintenanceConflicts-edit.php',
        datatype: 'xml',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:['Conflict Code', 'Description', 'Updated By', 'Updated On'], // Set column names of the grid
        colModel :[ // Set the settings for each individual column of the grid
            {
                name:'conflictCode', 
                index:'conflictCode', 
                width:120, 
                align:'center', 
                editable:false, 
            }, 
            {name:'description', index:'description', width:200, editable:true, edittype:"text"}, 
            {name:'updatedBy', index:'updatedBy', width:120, editable:true, edittype:"text", editrules: {required: true}}, 
            {name:'updatedOn', index:'updatedOn', width:120, editable:false, editrules: {required: true}}
        ], 
        pager: '#pager-maintenance-conflicts', 
        rowNum:10, // To start, the user will see 10 records on the first page
        rowList:[10,15,20], // How many records is the user able to see per page?
        sortname: 'conflictCode',
        sortorder: 'desc', // Order the 'sortname' should be sorted in
        viewrecords: true, // View the records upon grid startup? or wait until a search?
        caption: 'Maintenance | Conflicts' // Title of the grid (at the top)
    }).navGrid('#pager-maintenance-conflicts',{
        edit:true,
        add:true,
        view:true,
        del:true,
        search:true,
        refresh:true
    });

// ADD
$("#add_table-maintenance-conflicts").click(function(){

    jQuery("#table-maintenance-conflicts").jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",{
        mtype: 'POST',
        reloadAfterSubmit:false, 
        closeAfterAdd:true,         
    });

});

// EDIT
$("#edit_table-maintenance-conflicts").click(function(){

    var gr = jQuery("#table-maintenance-conflicts").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    if( gr != null ) 
        jQuery("#table-maintenance-conflicts").jqGrid('editGridRow',gr,{
            mtype: 'POST',
            reloadAfterSubmit:false, 
            closeAfterEdit:true
        });

});

// DELETE
$("#del_table-maintenance-conflicts").click(function(){

    var gr = jQuery("#table-maintenance-conflicts").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    if( gr != null ) 
        jQuery("#table-maintenance-conflicts").jqGrid('delGridRow',gr,{
            mtype: 'POST',
            reloadAfterSubmit:false
        });

});
```

Here is my maintenanceConflicts-edit.php file:

```
<?php 

//include the information needed for the connection to MySQL data base server. 
// we store here username, database and password 
$dbhost = "localhost";

$dbuser = "root";

$dbpassword = "";

$database = "ftdbadmin";

// connect to the database
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());
//echo "Connected to MySQL <br />";

// select the database
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Error conecting to db.");
//echo "Connected to the selected database: ".$database."<br />";

//  If we're ADDING
if($_POST['oper']=='add')
{

}

// If we're EDITING
if($_POST['oper']=='edit')
{
    $conflictCode     =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['conflictCode']);
    $description   =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
    $updatedBy =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['updatedBy']);
   // $updatedOn    =   mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['updatedOn']);

$SQL = "UPDATE tblconflict SET updatedBy = '".$updatedBy."', description = '".$description."' WHERE conflictCode = ".$conflictCode;

    echo $SQL;
    $result=mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_close($db);
}

// If we're DELETING
if($_POST['oper']=='del')
{

}

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Check this link http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=617

Comment: Thanks Andrey, but that blog post looks like it focuses on the commercial product, jQGrid for PHP...

Comment: It's very strange to me.. I've been searching everywhere and can't find ANY good examples of how to implement Add/Edit/Delete functions with my grid... Anyone have any examples or tutorials they know of?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I managed to figure this out a few months ago by poking around the Wiki, Google, and here on this site. I stumbled across this PHP CRUD template for jQGrid. With a little tweaking, I got it working with all my grids. Once you begin to work with it more, you will notice lots of room for improvement and expansion. It should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Please consider providing the solution directly in your answer. As it is, it qualifies for a link-only answer which doesn't satisfy SO standards.

Comment: @BartoszKP The link IS the answer. Why would I needlessly copy/paste the contents of the link?

Comment: It's not needlessly, as the link might get invalidated. And it IS currently established SO policy. Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95691/231717) for example, and perhaps tons of other meta discussions on this if you're really interested. Either way, the consensus is that link-only answers are not welcome.

Comment: @BartoszKP so what if (as in this case) there are links within the link? Or downloadable files within the link? Would be nice if SO had a file upload feature for answers, instead of expecting us to type it all here

Comment: I don't know. I only know, that either you can post an answer that meets SO quality standards or not. If you can, please go ahead. If you can't, you shouldn't - you can post a comment instead. Otherwise the answer will be most likely deleted.

Comment: @FastTrack you can solve your own "problems" by using a proper browser plugin. (For me it's basically Vim `:%y+`, then paste; `:%>|%y+|u` for code samples). No one in his right mind types anything non-trivial into finicky browsers (modulo extensions)

Comment: @BartoszKP well in this case, they can delete this answer if they so desire. There's too much to copy/paste along with the downloadable file(s). Just unfortunate if there people in the future who may have been helped by this link. But oh well for them I suppose.